# "code="internalError Rendering process failed Must have at least 2 spatial dimensions".how to solve this?

Tags: web-applications, mapping, gis, shapefile, geoserver

Sir/Madam, I have published the shape file in Geoserver. I am getting this error while I am trying the layer preview  - **"code="internalError Rendering process failed Must have at least 2 spatial dimensions"**. how to solve this?

[image: screenshot]

I have shared the screenshot of the output error in the above screenshot named link.

I am also sharing a shapefile in the below link.
[Drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aH1ziCErhvyL-kbUqonhItH070lrIjyR?usp=sharing)
In the output, I want to preview the layer.

Comment: It looks like your shapefile is broken some how, can you share it or post the output from `ogrinfo`

Comment: @IanTurton I have edited and shared the drive link of the shape file folder in the post named as Drive link.

Comment: You'll need to add more detail of the version of GeoServer, operating system etc and the exact steps you followed to import the shapefile as it works perfectly for me with 2.23.2

Comment: The user that runs GeoServer must have write permission to the data directory where you store your shapefiles to allow it to create the index files as needed

Comment: @IanTurton I have updated my GeoServer version to the latest release, which is now 2.23.2. Additionally, I have installed JDK 11 64-bit. Now it's working.  .

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, I have successfully adjusted the permissions. As a result, the system is now functioning properly.